# Beamer: content in box register does not survive \end{frame}

Tags: beamer, boxes, grouping

Consider the following example (I **edited** the example to include LaTeX `lrbox` environment):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newsavebox\mybox
\newsavebox\myboxb

\begin{document}
\frame{
  \sbox\mybox{Hello World!}\usebox\mybox %works

  \begin{lrbox}\myboxb Bonjour!\end{lrbox}\usebox\myboxb %works
}

\frame{
  \usebox\mybox %is empty

  \usebox\myboxb %is empty
}
\end{document}
```

Why is it that the second frame is blank? Is there possibly a workaround?

Comment: Would it be an option to put `\sbox\mybox{Hello World!}` into the preamble? Would also have global effect.

Answer (score 12):

Use `\global`, to let `\sbox` have global effect. Otherwise it's local, within the scope of the `frame` environment.

```
\begin{frame}
  \global\sbox\mybox{Hello World!}
  \usebox\mybox
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Well, not quite satisfied. I actually want to use `\begin{lrbox}\mybox ...\end{lrbox}`. What can I do here to make the assignment global?

Comment: @AlexanderGrahn: Perhaps post this actual problem with `lrbox` with a new example as another question, since it seems to be different.

Comment: @AlexanderGrahn: You could use `\global\setbox\mybox=\box\mybox` after the `lrbox` environment to make the assignment global.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Thanks! I like the idea of globally overwriting the box register content with itself. So redefining \setbox into a global command, as proposed by egreg, is not necessary. Could you add this as a separate answer?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `\global\sbox` (but `\global\savebox` won't work); for a "global" `lrbox` you can define your own environment:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\cslet{lrbox*}\lrbox
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname lrbox*\endcsname{\setbox}{\global\setbox}{}{}
%\expandafter\show\csname lrbox*\endcsname % uncomment to see if it has worked
\cslet{endlrbox*}\endlrbox
```

Now

```
\begin{lrbox*}{\mybox}
Hello world!
\end{lrbox*}
```

will set globally the contents of `\mybox`.

Comment: Why can't you create another box, say `\myotherbox` and then do something like `\global\savebox\myotherbox{\usebox{\mybox}}` before exiting the environment?

Comment: @A.Ellett Because you can't use `\global` in front of `\savebox`; one could do with `\global\sbox`, but this adds a level of boxing.