# lrbox in \newenvironment

Tags: environments, boxes

I cannot make `lrbox` work if put within a `\newenvironment`. I'll explain with an example. If I write:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
     \hfill
      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
         \noindent
         \textbf{ABSTRACT} \\
         Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
         \\
         \\
       \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{document}

\usebox{\mybox}

\end{document}
```

Then I obtain the result I want. But if I try to create a new environment that has to behave like the code above, I obtain a blank page. Specifically, if I write:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newenvironment{myenv}
{
   \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
     \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
     \hfill
     \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
        \noindent
        \textbf{ABSTRACT} \\
}{
        \\
        \\
     \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
   \end{lrbox}
}

\begin{myenv}
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
\end{myenv}

\begin{document}

\usebox{\mybox}

\end{document}
```

I obtain a blank page. Is anyone able to explain me why, please?

Comment: Special case of [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way).

Answer (score 14):

The environment makes a group and so the local setting of `\mybox` is discarded. the lrbox command has some code to "unwind" one level of grouping from a latex environment so that its normal use leaves the box defined after `\end{lrbox}` but this only undoes one level. I think @tohez answer is safe here, or an alternative, which similarly abuses LaTeX syntax a bit is to trick lrbox into making a global assignment

Changing your call to

```
 \begin{lrbox}{0\null\global\setbox\mybox}
```

will work (it makes a local assignment to box 0 then globally assigns the body of the environment to your box)

Comment: Would you consider this a good way to store an environment's body in a box for further processing? Is there a better way?

Comment: @user1129682 not really. I'd use tohez (user now called yo') answer or simply use `\begin{lrbox}{0}....\end{lrbox}\global\setbox\mybox\box0` so lrbox locally saves the box then you globally copy it to `\mybox`.

Answer (score 8):

**If you substitute `\begin{lrbox}`->`\lrbox` and `\end{lrbox}`->`\endlrbox`, it works perfectly.**

There seem to be some problem with calling `\begin{mybox}...\end{mybox}`, because every `\begin{ENV}...\end{ENV}` pair encloses the contents into an extra pair of `\begingroup...\endgroup`, which are TeX primitives that makes box assignments local.

In the solution, the `\begingroup` from `\begin{mybox}` is undone by `\lrbox`, but would not be undone by `\begin{lrbox}` since in that case only `\begingroup` from `\begin{lrbox}` is undone. (And the same applies for `\end{lrbox}` and `\endgroup`.)

Remark: You can write `\ENV...\endENV` for any environment, but it changes their behaviour and the result can be unpredictable.

(Thanks @Stephan and @Martin for comments.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newenvironment{myenv}
{
   \lrbox\mybox
     \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
     \hfill
     \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
        \noindent
        \textbf{ABSTRACT}
}{
     \end{minipage}
    \end{minipage}
   \endlrbox
}

\begin{myenv}
Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 
\end{myenv}

\begin{document}

\usebox{\mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Uh, the other way round... `\lrbox` explicitly **starts** with `\endgroup` to undo the `\begingroup` from `\begin{lrbox}`. The way you use it here, the `\endgroup` can undo the  `\begingroup` from `\begin{myenv}`.

Comment: This solution is correct, but some extra explanation would be good. It doesn't "changes the behaviour of boxes", it simply places them into a group, which makes the box assignment local. I assume you meant that. `lrbox` is quite special because it needs to cancel the usual environment group out. It works well inside another environment as long you are using the box register only within it. Your solution makes the `lrbox` code cancels out the group added by the `myenv` environment and makes the box assignment accessible by the outside scope (like @StephanLehmke already mentioned).

Comment: A curiosity. Is the problem that the article.cls redefines the normal behavior of the lrbox environment, or is this behavior the standard \begin{lrbox}\end{lrbox} behavior?

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thanks for the comments, updated.

Comment: @Michele I believe that `lrbox` is defined this way in all standard classes. It is simply that some commands cause trouble inside environments.

Comment: @tohecz Note that any assignment performed before `\lrbox` in the "begin" part will be ignored and this might cause some surprise: with `\newenvironment{myenv}{\itshape\lrbox\mybox...}{\endlrbox}` the text inside the built box will *not* be in italics.

Comment: @egreg No solution is perfect...

Comment: @tohecz -- `lrbox` is actually defined in `latex.ltx`.  i don't know of any document classes that redefine it; certainly not the basic latex classes or the ams classes.

Answer (score 5):

The box is assigned locally by `lrbox`. Hence, the end of your environment undoes the assignment.

Try the `lrbox*` construct from [this posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43046/12850).