# local commands are not recognized when trying to define a wrapper lrbox

Tags: boxes

I can't get the following code to work correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@ae@nfig@verb@
\pgfkeys
  {%%'
  /ae/nfigverb/.is family,
  /ae/nfigverb,
    usegobble/.initial=,
    gobble/.style = { usegobble={gobble=#1,}},
    width/.initial=3in,
  }

\newsavebox{\aetitlebox}
\newenvironment{nfigverb}[1][]
  {%%'
    \pgfqkeys{/ae/nfigverb}{#1}%%'
    \edef\ae@begin@minipage{%%'
      \noexpand\minipage{\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/nfigverb/width}}}%%'
    \lrbox\aetitlebox
      \ae@begin@minipage
  }
  {%%'
   \endminipage
    \endlrbox
  }

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{nfigverb}[width=3in]
  as;lfk slfjksd flsk fls dfls
\end{nfigverb}

\usebox{\aetitlebox}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\\nfigverb ...rbox \aetitlebox \ae@begin@minipage 

l.32 \begin{nfigverb}[width=3in]

?
```

Because of the way I intend to use keys for setting parameters of various environments, I seem to need to go the route here of `\noexpand` on the macro specifying the environment name so that passed options get parsed correctly.

**Note**

This is actually part of a bigger question.  But I couldn't even get this little snippet of code to work.

I seem to be able to fix this if I write:

```
\newenvironment{nfigverb}[1][]
  {%%'
    \lrbox\aetitlebox
    \pgfqkeys{/ae/nfigverb}{#1}%%'
    \edef\ae@begin@minipage{%%'
      \noexpand\minipage{\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/nfigverb/width}}}%%'
      \ae@begin@minipage
  }
  {%%'
   \endminipage
    \endlrbox
  }
```

I don't understand why this change makes any difference to what I'm using inside this environment.  An explanation would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

I'm trying to follow @tohecz 's answer at [lrbox in \newenvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49133/22413).

The problem I'm having is that

```
\newenvironment{nfigverb}...
   {\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
     ....}{\end{lrbox}}
```

will not let me later call

```
 \usebox{\mybox}
```

and print the contents from this new box.

Comment: ***Never*** use `\lrbox...\endlrbox`, but always `\begin{lrbox}...\end{lrbox}`, because this environment does an `\endgroup` that is exactly the cause of your problem.

Comment: @egreg But as I understand things, if I use `\begin{lrbox}`, then the box is emptied once I leave the new environment.  I need to use the box later in my document.

Comment: @A.Ellett no, lrbox is designed to be an environment so begin/end works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the definition of `\lrbox`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 4634:
\def\lrbox#1{%
  \edef\reserved@a{%
    \endgroup
    \setbox#1\hbox{%
      \begingroup\aftergroup}%
        \def\noexpand\@currenvir{\@currenvir}%
        \def\noexpand\@currenvline{\on@line}}%
  \reserved@a
    \@endpefalse
    \color@setgroup
      \ignorespaces}
```

The `\endgroup` is there to match the `\begingroup` issued by `\begin` when `\begin{lrbox}` is executed. There are various reasons for this, but the main thing is that you should *never* use the `\lrbox...\endlrbox` form.

Also the `\edef` is useless, but you must set `\aetitlebox` globally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@ae@nfig@verb@
\pgfkeys
  {%%'
  /ae/nfigverb/.is family,
  /ae/nfigverb,
    usegobble/.initial=,
    gobble/.style = { usegobble={gobble=#1,}},
    width/.initial=3in,
  }

\newsavebox{\aetitlebox}
\newenvironment{nfigverb}[1][]
  {%
   \pgfqkeys{/ae/nfigverb}{#1}%
   \begin{lrbox}{\z@}
   \minipage{\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/nfigverb/width}}
  }
  {%
   \endminipage
   \end{lrbox}%
   \global\setbox\aetitlebox=\box\z@
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{nfigverb}[width=3in]
  as;lfk slfjksd flsk fls dfls
\end{nfigverb}

\usebox{\aetitlebox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\edef` is there for other reasons.  I reduced a lot of my code here.  In my actual code I need the `\edef` to pass optional arguments to the minipage before it gets expanded.  `\edef` is not there for any *global* purposes.

Comment: This works for the MWE I posted above.  I'm posting another question, but your solution, while it works for what I asked here, still doesn't work in my actual document.