# When is it safe to assume that \begin{<env_name>} and \<env_name> do the same thing

Tags: environments

I've been under, apparently, the misapprehension that if you have defined an environment called `<env_name>` then `\begin<env_name>` and `\<env_name>` accomplish the same thing.  But considering [@egreg 's admonishment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125954/22413) and [my attempts to implement his suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125957/22413), I see that I'm quite wrong.

Occasionally I want to define a new environment, or a command that invokes an environment, in a manner where too early expansion of `\begin{<env_name>}` will result in errors.  Here's a MWE of what I'm thinking of:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys
  {
    /ae/mwe/.is family,
    /ae/mwe,
   usegobble/.initial=,
   gobble/.style = { usegobble={gobble=#1,} },
  }
\newenvironment{aetestingmwe}[1][]
  {%%'
    \pgfqkeys{/ae/mwe}{#1}%%'
    \edef\ae@begin@verbatim
      {%%'
        \noexpand\Verbatim[\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/mwe/usegobble}]}%%'
    \ae@begin@verbatim
  }
  {
    \endVerbatim
  }
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{aetestingmwe}
  [
    gobble=2,
  ]
  \textbf{Random stuff}
This line will get decapitated!
\end{aetestingmwe}

\end{document}
```

If I try to define the environment as

```
\newenvironment{aetestingmwe}[1][]
  {%%'
    \pgfqkeys{/ae/mwe}{#1}%%'
    \begin{Verbatim}[\pgfkeysvalueof{/ae/mwe/usegobble}]
  }
  {
    \end{Verbatim}
  }
```

I'll get an error:

```
! Package keyval Error: gobble=2, undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.27   ]

?
```

So it seems that it is sometimes necessary to use `\<env_name>` in place of `\begin{<env_name>}`.

How do I know when it's safe to assume these two are the same?  When are they different?  Does it matter whether the environment was defined using low level commands or LaTeX's `\newenvironment`?  What about environments created using `xparse`?

Comment: The only environments that are unsafe in this respect are `document` and `lrbox` that, for different reasons, issue `\endgroup` in the starting part and `\begingroup` in the finishing part. Verbatim environment definitions should never use `\begin` and `\end` in their arguments.

Comment: See also [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\begin{<env_name>}` and `\<env_name>` almost never do the same thing.

In the usual case

```
\begin{<env_name>}
```

is (apart from error checking) the same as

```
\begingroup\<env_name>
```

The extra grouping may or may not matter depending on the code in question.

So what are the unusual cases ...

- `document`

  For efficiency reasons the `document` environment doesn't form a group. The definition of `\document` starts with `\endgroup` so if you use `\document` on its own you would get an error, but as noted above the thing you should be comparing to is `\begingroup\document` which would in fact work. (But you shouldn't be nesting `document` environments anyway.)
- `lrbox`

  As with `document`, `lrbox` requires the outer group so you need to use `\begingroup\lrbox`... `\endlrbox\endgroup` if you want to avoid the environment form. Here the issue is that `lrbox` locally saves its contents in a box register so uses some `\aftergroup` trickery so the box register has that value *after* the environment. If you use `\lrbox` not surrounded by a group then this `\aftergroup` token will appear somewhere but probably not where you intended.
- Environments with `\ignorespacesafterend` in their end-code.

  This command just sets a boolean flag which is picked up in the definition of `\end` which causes it to issue `\ignorespaces`. So if you use `\end<env_name>` instead of `\end{env_name}` the `\ignorespaces` will be issued by the `\end` that does end the current group, will not be issued at all if the group ends with `}` or `\endgroup` explicitly.  This may be the behaviour you want but it is in any case a difference.
- verbatim-like environments

  Inside `verbatim` and similar macros `\end` does not trigger the command `\end` as `\` is not special, `\end` is just the four tokens `\` `e` `n` `d` . So that it works like an environment the definition uses a delimited argument macro defined as if by

  ```
  \def\@@@something#1\end{verbatim}{...}
  ```

  This means that the expected environment name such as `\end{verbatim}` has to appear literally in the document. `\endverbatim` (even with a suitable catcode setup) will not form the end delimiter for such a macro.

  In the original `verbatim` definition in LaTeX, `verbatim` is explicit in the code so the environment can not be nested in macros at all. The `verbatim` (and most late packages) make this a bit more flexible in that if you use `\verbatim` rather than `\begin{verbatim}` the `\verbatim` code will pick up the name of the *current* environment and use that to define the delimited macro (or other tests) that terminate the environment. Thus `Verbatim` and `listings` etc can be nested in another environment definition if they are called as macros but not if the `\begin` `\end` form is used internally.
- environments that grab their body as a macro argument.

  Some environments (notably and possibly originally `amsmath` environments such as `align`), `tabularx`, and any environment defined via the `environ` package definitions.
  use a mechanism similar to that described above for `verbatim` to grab their body via a macro argument (and defined as the macro `\BODY` in the case of `environ`.

Comment: Very thorough write up.  I appreciate the details.