# Tikz node not showing saved box

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

I have a series of complicated content I'm trying to present using TikZ.  The code is highly regular, so I wanted to write  a simple command to handle everything.  In the following code, `\aelabelA` and `\aelabelC` are not working properly at all and I don't understand why.  However, `\aelabelB` does work.  Could someone explain why the content of the boxes for scenario A and C is not visible?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newsavebox\aebox
\NewDocumentCommand\aelabelA{ mu{~located~at~(}u{);} }
  {
    \begin{lrbox}{\aebox}
      \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \Large\ttfamily\bfseries
        \centering\makebox[0pt]{#1}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}
    \node[draw] ~ at~  (#3)  ~ {\usebox{\aebox}};
  }

\NewDocumentCommand\aelabelB{ m }
  {
    \begin{lrbox}{\aebox}
      \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \Large\ttfamily\bfseries
        \centering\makebox[0pt]{#1}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}
    \usebox{\aebox}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\aelabelC#1 located at (#2);{%%
    \begin{lrbox}{\aebox}
      \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \Large\ttfamily\bfseries
        \centering\makebox[0pt]{#1}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}%%
    \node[draw] at (#2) {\usebox{\aebox}};
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (AA) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (BB) at (2,2);
  \coordinate (CC) at (4,4);

  \aelabelA {Keys} located at (AA);

  \node[draw] at (BB) {\aelabelB{Keys}};

  \aelabelC{Keys} located at (CC);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's indeed a bit curious. (+1) However, if you put something in your tikzpicture (but *not* in a node), this will be gobbled. Isn't that just what happens to the contents of the `lrboxes`? As you see in your example B, if you do the `lrbox` inside a node, it won't be gobbled. If you could explain what you really want to do, perhaps there is a way with the usual Ti*k*Z/pgf methods.

Comment: @marmot omg. that's probably the problem. thank you. write up your comment as an answer and i'll accept later when i get back to my computer and test everything out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ti*k*Z is known to gobble ordinary stuff inside `tikzpicture` environments *unless* this stuff is in a node. You can interrupt the `tikzpicture` in order to evade from getting ignored, and you need a bit globalization to make it work. I fixed your first command in this fashion but left the last one as it was for pedagogical purposes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newsavebox\aebox
\NewDocumentCommand\aelabelA{ mu{~located~at~(}u{);} }
  {\begin{pgfinterruptpicture}
    \begin{lrbox}{0\null\global\setbox\aebox} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49129/lrbox-in-newenvironment/49136#49136
      \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \Large\ttfamily\bfseries
        \centering\makebox[0pt]{#1}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}
    \end{pgfinterruptpicture}
    \node[draw] ~ at~  (#3)  ~ {\usebox{\aebox}};
  }

\NewDocumentCommand\aelabelB{ m }
  {
    \begin{lrbox}{\aebox}
      \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \Large\ttfamily\bfseries
        \centering\makebox[0pt]{#1}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}
    \usebox{\aebox}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\aelabelC#1 located at (#2);{%%
    \begin{lrbox}{\aebox}
      \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \Large\ttfamily\bfseries
        \centering\makebox[0pt]{#1}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}%%
    \node[draw] at (#2) {\usebox{\aebox}};
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (AA) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (BB) at (2,2);
  \coordinate (CC) at (4,4);

  \aelabelA {Keys} located at (AA);

  \node[draw] at (BB) {\aelabelB{Keys}};

  \aelabelC{Keys} located at (CC);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: A somewhat cleaner alternative due to @egreg (mille grazie!) with the same output.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newsavebox\aebox
\NewDocumentCommand\aelabelA{ mu{~located~at~(}u{);} }
  {\begin{pgfinterruptpicture}
    \begin{lrbox}{0}%
      \begin{minipage}{1in}%
        \Large\ttfamily\bfseries
        \centering\makebox[0pt]{#1}%
      \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \global\setbox\aebox=\box0
    \end{pgfinterruptpicture}
    \node[draw] ~ at~  (#3)  ~ {\usebox{\aebox}};
  }

\NewDocumentCommand\aelabelB{ m }
  {
    \begin{lrbox}{\aebox}
      \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \Large\ttfamily\bfseries
        \centering\makebox[0pt]{#1}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}
    \usebox{\aebox}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\aelabelC#1 located at (#2);{%%
    \begin{lrbox}{\aebox}
      \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \Large\ttfamily\bfseries
        \centering\makebox[0pt]{#1}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}%%
    \node[draw] at (#2) {\usebox{\aebox}};
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (AA) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (BB) at (2,2);
  \coordinate (CC) at (4,4);

  \aelabelA {Keys} located at (AA);

  \node[draw] at (BB) {\aelabelB{Keys}};

  \aelabelC{Keys} located at (CC);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

A macro for creating `\savebox`es inside a `tikzpicture` has been created in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449145/savebox-doesnt-work-inside-tikz-foreach-loop?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I suggest the cleaner `\begin{lrbox}{0}...\end{lrbox}\global\setbox\aebox=\box0`