# \savebox doesn't work inside tikz foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, foreach

I need to process listed content passed to a `\foreach` loop inside a `tikz` environment. But `\savebox` seems not to behave the same as outside `tikz`.

In particular, the following code:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\aBox}

\newcommand{\withoutTikz}[1]{%
    \foreach \content [count=\i] in {#1} {%
        \savebox{\aBox}{\content}% store content in the box..
        \i : \usebox{\aBox}% use the box

    }%
}

\newcommand{\withinTikz}[1]{%
\tikz{% within tikz..
    \foreach \content [count=\i] in {#1} {%
        \savebox{\aBox}{\content}% store content in the box the same way..
        \node at (0, -.5*\i) {\i : \usebox{\aBox}}; % .. but now it seems empty!
    }%
}
}

\begin{document}

\withoutTikz{a,b,c}

\withinTikz{a,b,c}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: no tikz boxes!]

Why? Am I missing anything?
How do I get this `aBox` content updated on each iteration within the tikz environment?

---

[EDIT:] Problem duplicated [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448576/72679). Based on [marmot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448581/72679) there, here is how I have solved it :)

```
\newcommand{\tikzSaveBox}[2]{
     \begin{pgfinterruptpicture}%
     \begin{lrbox}{0\null\global\setbox\csname#1\endcsname}%
     #2
     \end{lrbox}%
     \end{pgfinterruptpicture}
}

\newcommand{\withinTikz}[1]{%
 \tikz{% within tikz..
     \foreach \content [count=\i] in {#1} {%
     \tikzSaveBox{aBox}{\content} % special case within tikz
     \node at (0, -.5*\i) {\i : \usebox{\aBox}}; % .. now it works fine :)
     }%
}
}
```

Comment: Because in Ti*k*Z pictures things get gobbled unless they are in a node, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448576/121799).

Comment: You could make your command within Ti*k*Z work using e.g. `\newcommand{\withinTikz}[1]{%
\tikz{% within tikz..
    \foreach \content [count=\i] in {#1} {%
  \begin{pgfinterruptpicture}%
  \begin{lrbox}{0\null\global\setbox\aBox} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49129/lrbox-in-newenvironment/49136#49136
  \content
     \end{lrbox}%
  \end{pgfinterruptpicture}
        \node at (0, -.5*\i) {\i : \usebox{\aBox}}; % .. but now it seems empty!
    }%
}
}`.

Comment: @marmot Jeez! Well, I have tried to `{\begin{pgfinterruptpicture}\global\savebox{\aBox}{\content}\end{pgfinterruptpicture}}` it instead, but it seems not to make any difference.. How do I [interrupt-and-globalize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448581/72679) in this case? Thank you for informing about this gobbling process anyway :) Any reason why tikz does so? -\_-"

Comment: @marmot Wow, this works indeed, cheers for that :) How come we end up with soo complicated patterns? X(

Comment: Please see my 2nd comment for how this can be made work. I guess one reason why Ti*k*Z wants to gobble these things is convenience: otherwise empty lines ore simple spaces will screw up every Ti*k*Z picture. In my comment above I also had to place `%`s after `\begin{pgfinterruptpicture}` and `\end{lrbox}` for that reason. I guess you have the choice between the current behavior of Ti*k*Z and a bit more complicated syntax if you want to define `\savebox`es inside a `tikzpicture` or an orgy of `%` and less complicated `\savebox`es. I'd go for the first option.

Comment: @marmot I see. I have improved readability a little bit with `% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448581/72679
\newcommand{\tikzSaveBox}[2]{%
     \begin{pgfinterruptpicture}%
     \begin{lrbox}{0\null\global\setbox\csname#1\endcsname}%
     #2
     \end{lrbox}%
     \end{pgfinterruptpicture}
}`, which seems to work well. Thank you for your patience anyway :)

Comment: Yes, that's more structured.  Do you have any objections of your question being closed as a duplicate? (A question being duplicate is does not mean that the question is of lower value, just someone else happened to ask that question earlier.) I won't close it without your permission.

Comment: @marmot No worries. Please proceed. I'll post my "more structured" command as an edit to [your answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448581/72679) there, also only with your permission :)

Comment: No, please post an independent answer there. Of course, you might want to say that your answer is based on mine. Or append this trick simply to your question. (I never understood the duplicate thingy completely.)

Comment: @marmot Okay, I'll append it here then :)