# Arrows around figure - no TikZ

Tags: floats, alignment

I currently have a grid of figures as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[verbose,margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\newcommand{\xdownarrow}[1]{%
  {\left\downarrow\vbox to #1{}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \hspace{0.6cm}$\pmb{\xrightarrow{\hspace{2.3cm}label1\hspace{2.9cm}label2\hspace{2.4cm}label3\hspace{2.95cm}label4\hspace{2.2cm}}}$
        \\[-0.4cm]
        \begin{minipage}[t][14.2cm][b]{0.01\linewidth}
            \rotatebox{90}{$\pmb{vlabel1}$}
            \vfill
            \rotatebox{90}{$\pmb{vlabel2}$}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.01\linewidth}
            $\pmb{\xdownarrow{7.4cm}}$
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t][][b]{0.97\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[trim=0.0cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\linewidth]{{image1}.pdf}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\linewidth]{{image2}.pdf}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\linewidth]{{image3}.pdf}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\linewidth]{{image4}.pdf}\\
            \includegraphics[trim=0.0cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\linewidth]{{image5}.pdf}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\linewidth]{{image6}.pdf}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\linewidth]{{image6}.pdf}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\linewidth]{{image8}.pdf}\\
            \includegraphics[trim=0.0cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\linewidth]{{image9}.pdf}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\linewidth]{{image10}.pdf}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\linewidth]{{image11}.pdf}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\linewidth]{{image12}.pdf}\\
            \includegraphics[trim=0.0cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\linewidth]{{image13}.pdf}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\linewidth]{{image14}.pdf}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\linewidth]{{image15}.pdf}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\linewidth]{{image16}.pdf}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This generates a 4x4 grid of images, with a right arrow above with 4 labels spaces, and a down arrow to the left with two spaced labels. Those hard-coded lengths are not practical. As this will not be the last time I need to make such a figure, how can I get the above to work properly? I want the following to happen automatically through the scaling of the 3d mini-page, with the figures:

1. Arrow above spans entire horizontal range of the grid
2. Above said arrow 4 labels spaced equally, such that they are centered on each plot horizontally
3. To the left an arrow spanning the entire vertical range of the grid
4. Two labels rotated to the left of said arrow, the upper one ending at the start of the arrow, the lower one starting at the end

The main problem is that the lengths are somehow not set, so I cannot use `\vfill` and `\hfill` properly, nor are the mini-pages aligned without specifying that first height. If the figures minipage could be set before the rest of the figure elements, perhaps then all the lengths (text height, line width etc.) will be set.

I do not want a `tikz` solution, but am open to dropping the mini-pages or anything else.

Comment: Would a picture (pict2e package) overlay be acceptable?

Comment: @JohnKormylo anything that doesn't feel like I need to program a drawing from scratch. I am looking for an easy to write, flexible solution, that doesn't require me to set nodes, anchors, coordinates and the like. I feel something like "an arrow the entire length of the figure" should be easy to do.

Comment: The picture environment has few capabilities, but it can draw arrows and labels.  It is built into LaTeX, pict2e mostly allows better diagonal lines.

Comment: OTOH, I would have to replace all your images with something available to me, like example-image.

Comment: @JohnKormylo the name of everything is just for the example, of course you need your own images to test :). Thanks.

Comment: Also the grid size doesn't matter- the solution should not depend on it (or should depend on it on a single line).

Comment: @kabanus for the future: There are several image files contained in a modern TeX distribution to use in MWEs: `example-image-duck`, `example-image`, `example-image-a`, `example-image-b` (to name a few).

Comment: @Skillmon oh wow, thanks, I was unfamiliar.

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to use TikZ?  It seems that without TikZ we're reinventing the wheel.  The TikZ solution needn't be complicated and can avoid much of the headache you appear to mention in your question, but without TikZ you're more likely to get something that is much less flexible.

Comment: @A.Ellett I had one, it was twice as long as the solution above, and I did not want to memorize it. The point is, I need something that doesn't need to be flexible at all, just two arrows stretched across the entire figure - I want to do this with both short and scalable code. `tikz` is the metaphorical cannon to this fly of a problem (or so I thought?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer in three parts.

**Part 1: a partial non-TikZ solution**

Here's the start of a solution that does not resort to TikZ.  There's definitely room for improvement.  But this is surely better than what I posted earlier for a non-TikZ approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\graphicspath{{../images/}}

\newcommand{\myxdownarrow}[2]{%%                        
  %% use raisebox here to shift the vertical arrow down 
  %% so that it appears to only span the portion of the 
  %% table contains the images                          
  \raisebox{-3ex}[0.5\dimexpr#1]{$\pmb{\left\downarrow\rule[-0.5\dimexpr#1-3ex]{0pt}{\dimexpr#1-3ex}\right.}$}}%%
\newcommand{\myxrightarrow}[1]{%%
  %% use raisebox here to shift the horizontal arrow down
  %% so that it appears below the labels across the top of
  %% the table
  \raisebox{-4ex}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox{90}{$\pmb{\left\downarrow\rule[-0.5\dimexpr#1]{0pt}{#1}\right.}$}}}%%

\newsavebox\aepic
\newlength\aelength

\newsavebox\aepicA
\newsavebox\aepicB
\newsavebox\aepicC
\newsavebox\aepicD

\makeatletter

\newtoks\ae@tok@master

%% ------------------------------------------------------------     
%% two arguments:                                                   
%% ARG #1=label for the row being created                           
%% ARG #2=contents of the row                                       
%%        foreach each cell three pieces need to be passed          
%%                                                                  
%%        * optional arguments for \includegraphics                 
%%        * file handle for image to be used                        
%%        * the name of a save box for this particular image        
%%                                                                  
%%        which will be used by an internal command \ae@process@item
%% ------------------------------------------------------------     
\newcommand\aejustrow[2]{%%
  \ae@tok@master={}%%
  \def\ae@wd{0pt}%%
  \def\ae@ht{0pt}%%
  \def\ae@row@label{#1}%%
  \ae@row@content#2;\relax;\relax\end@row@content
  \expandafter\typeout\expandafter{\the\ae@tok@master}%%
  \rotatebox{90}{\makebox[\ae@ht][c]{#1}} \the\ae@tok@master 
}

%% 
\def\ae@row@content#1;#2\end@row@content{%%
  \ifx\relax#1
    \def\ae@continue{}%%
  \else
    \ae@process@item#1;%%
    \def\ae@continue{\ae@row@content#2\end@row@content}%%
  \fi
  \ae@continue
  }

%% ARG #1 = options to be passed to \includegraphics
%% ARG #2 = image file handle
%% ARG #3 = savebox name
\def\ae@process@item#1#2#3;{%%
  %% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49136/22413
  %% for what's going on with `0\null\global....`
  \begin{lrbox}{0\null\global\setbox#3}%%
    \includegraphics#1{#2}%%
  \end{lrbox}%%
  %% determine the maximal height of the images being used.
  \ifdim\ae@ht<\ht#3%%
    \xdef\ae@ht{\the\ht#3}%%
  \fi
  \ae@tok@master=\expandafter{\the\ae@tok@master & \noexpand\usebox{#3}}%%
  }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

        \setlength\aelength{\dimexpr0.97\linewidth-3ex}%%
        \begin{lrbox}\aepic
          \setlength\tabcolsep{0.5pt}%%
          \begin{tabular}[t]{c@{\hspace{1em}}cccc}
             \rule[-4ex]{0pt}{1pt}%% a vertical strut to get horizontal line under labels
              & label1 & label2 & label3 & label4 \\
              \aejustrow{vlable 1}{%%
                {[trim=0.0cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\aelength]}{image1.pdf}{\aepicA};
                {[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]}{image2.pdf}{\aepicB};
                {[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]}{image3.pdf}{\aepicC};
                {[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]}{image4.pdf}{\aepicD}} \\
              \aejustrow{vlable 2}{%%
                {[trim=0.0cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\aelength]}{image5.pdf}{\aepicA};
                {[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]}{image6.pdf}{\aepicB};
                {[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]}{image7.pdf}{\aepicC};
                {[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]}{image8.pdf}{\aepicD}} \\
              \aejustrow{vlable 3}{%%
                {[trim=0.0cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\aelength]}{image9.pdf}{\aepicA};
                {[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]}{image10.pdf}{\aepicB};
                {[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]}{image11.pdf}{\aepicC};
                {[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]}{image12.pdf}{\aepicD}} \\
              \aejustrow{vlable 4}{%%
                {[trim=0.0cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\aelength]}{image13.pdf}{\aepicA};
                {[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]}{image14.pdf}{\aepicB};
                {[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]}{image15.pdf}{\aepicC};
                {[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]}{image16.pdf}{\aepicD}}
          \end{tabular}
        \end{lrbox}%%

\begin{figure}
  \hspace{2em}\myxrightarrow{\dimexpr\wd\aepic -2.25em}\\[-0.4cm]%%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][\dimexpr\height+\depth]
      {\hspace*{1em}\myxdownarrow{\dimexpr\ht\aepic+\dp\aepic-1ex\relax}}}%%
  \raisebox{-\height}[0pt][\dimexpr\height+\depth]{\usebox\aepic}%%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This solution still doesn't feel fully satisfactory to me.  It seems to rigidly tied to one particular way of presenting the images and lacks the sort of flexibility I prefer.  Getting things to cooperate is a headache.  Nevertheless, I **do** hope this helps you produce the result you desired.

All of this work really feels like reinventing the wheel: there is potentially a lot of work needed to muck around in the innards of LaTeX.

There are lots of other packages available to help with such mark up.  JohnKormylo shows you how to do this with a `picture` environment.  Something similar could also be done using `pstricks`.  I'd like to sell you on `TikZ` though.  So that's what I'll look at for the rest of this posting.

**Part 2: The Bugaboo of TikZ**

So, I know you said you didn't want to use TikZ.  But, unless you have constraints coming from a publisher or advisor..., I feel you can get this done very easily and cleanly using TikZ.   So, here is my TikZ version of a solution.  I explain what I've done after the code for this solution.

[image]

Here's the code to produce this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,arrows.meta}
\newlength\aelength
\newbox\aepic

\newcommand\aegraphic[3][]  {%% 
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node (#2/BL) {};%%
  \tikz \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] (#2) at (#2/BL) {\includegraphics[#1]{#3}};%%
  }

\begin{document}

\setlength\aelength{\dimexpr\linewidth-3em}%%
\begin{figure}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt}%%
  \hspace*{3em}%%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{cccc}
      \aegraphic[trim=0.0cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\aelength]{A1}{{image1}.pdf} &
      \aegraphic[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{A2}{{image2}.pdf} &
      \aegraphic[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{A3}{{image3}.pdf} &
      \aegraphic[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{A4}{{image4}.pdf}\\
      %% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \aegraphic[trim=0.0cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\aelength]{B1}{{image5}.pdf} &
      \aegraphic[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{B2}{{image6}.pdf} &
      \aegraphic[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{B3}{{image7}.pdf} &
      \aegraphic[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{B4}{{image8}.pdf}\\
      %% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \aegraphic[trim=0.0cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\aelength]{C1}{{image9}.pdf}  &
      \aegraphic[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{C2}{{image10}.pdf} &
      \aegraphic[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{C3}{{image11}.pdf} &
      \aegraphic[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{C4}{{image12}.pdf}\\
      %% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \aegraphic[trim=0.0cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\aelength]{D1}{{image13}.pdf} &
      \aegraphic[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{D2}{{image14}.pdf} &
      \aegraphic[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{D3}{{image15}.pdf} &
      \aegraphic[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{D4}{{image16}.pdf}
  \end{tabular}%%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[fit=(A1) (A2) (A3) (A4)
                (B1) (B2) (B3) (B4)
                (C1) (C2) (C3) (C4)
                (D1) (D2) (D3) (D4),
                inner sep=0pt,
                ] (PIC) {};

      \draw[line width=1pt,arrows={-Stealth[length=4mm]}] ([xshift=-1em]PIC.north west) -- ([xshift=-1em]PIC.south west);
      \draw[line width=1pt,arrows={-Stealth[length=4mm]}] ([yshift=1em]PIC.north west) -- ([yshift=1em]PIC.north east);

      \node[anchor=south] (COL1/label) at ([yshift=1em]A1|-PIC.north) {Column Label  1};
      \node[anchor=south] (COL2/label) at ([yshift=1em]A2|-PIC.north) {Column Label  2};
      \node[anchor=south] (COL3/label) at ([yshift=1em]A3|-PIC.north) {Column Label  3};
      \node[anchor=south] (COL4/label) at ([yshift=1em]A4|-PIC.north) {Column Label  4};

      \node[anchor=center,rotate=90] (ROW1/label) at ([xshift=-1.5em]A1-|PIC.west) {ROW 1 label};
      \node[anchor=center,rotate=90] (ROW2/label) at ([xshift=-1.5em]B1-|PIC.west) {ROW 2 label};
      \node[anchor=center,rotate=90] (ROW3/label) at ([xshift=-1.5em]C1-|PIC.west) {ROW 3 label};
      \node[anchor=center,rotate=90] (ROW4/label) at ([xshift=-1.5em]D1-|PIC.west) {ROW 4 label};

      \node[blue,anchor=south] at (A1.north) {Description of first pic};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Explanation of TikZ solution**

I'm trying to minimize your headaches with TikZ here.  The key here is two-fold:  using a *overlays* and *fitting*.

I still use the `tabular` environment for laying out the picture.  This could be done in a Tikz Picture.  But, since I don't know all your potential constraints, I've forgone making the entire figure that way.  In particular, I don't know how you want to handle the alignment pictures of unequal height or width.

Each cell of `tabular` tabular environment has three things going on:

- A TikZ *mark* is created.  This is to help us later remember where the picture is.
- Using the TikZ mark, another TikZ node is created in which the image is going to be placed.  This will give us information about where the edges of the picture are that a TikZ mark doesn't provide.
- I define a command `\aegraphic` to simplify things a bit.  And, it makes the code more readable.  This command takes three arguments.  The first is optional and contains the key values you want to pass along to `\includegraphics`, the second argument is the name of the node in which you'll be placing the graphic, and the third argument is name of the image file.

Once the table of images is created, I create a `PIC` node to fit all the nodes of each individual graphic used.  Now I can easily determine where the arrows along the top and left of the image should be place.  I can also easily place labels adjacent to rows (properly rotated) and above each column.

The key points of TikZ that I use are the following:

- Anchoring:  this helps us place the elements of the picture relative to each other without know exactly where they are.
- Rotation: rotation happens around the *anchor* of the node.
- The `(<node_A>-|<node_B>)` syntax:  this grabs the `y` coordinate from node `A` and the `x` coordinate of node `B`.  Similarly `(<node_A>|-<node_B>)` just flips this around.
- The `([<options>]node-name)` syntax:  this allows fine tuning such as displacing the arrows along the edges of the image relative to the nodes defined by the table.
- `remember picture,overlay` syntax:  this is telling TikZ to remember where this picture is being placed, essentially allowing you to place the TikZ picture wherever you would like on the page irrespective of other content.

**Part 3:  a fully TikZ solution**

What's nice about this solution is using the TikZ matrix construct is very similar to using the `tabular` environment.  So, that means there's not too much more to learn there.  Also, `overlays` can be annoying since they can intrude into other parts of your document, which means you have to go in and manually fix things.  In this entirely TikZ solution, no such manual tweaking should be necessary.  And, other than using the `\matrix` command provided in the TikZ bundle, nothing else changes.  I probably do not need to use the fitting library here, but I have to run off to work and so I will leave that up to later to contemplate.

One issue I do have with the `tabular` environment approach is that, while setting the distance between columns is fairly straight-forward, there is no simple way to control to the same degree the distance between rows (at least I'm not aware of any, tell me about it in the comments if I'm wrong).   But, even if there were such a control, within TikZ I can easily control the presentation of the spacing around images with one *key* `inner sep=1pt` or whatever other value one wishes.

[image]

The code for this solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,arrows.meta}
\newlength\aelength

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \setlength\aelength{\dimexpr\linewidth-3em}%%
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \matrix[nodes={anchor=south west,inner sep=1pt}]{ 
    \node (A1) {\includegraphics[trim=0.0cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\aelength]{{image1}.pdf}};  & 
    \node (A2) {\includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{{image2}.pdf}};  & 
    \node (A3) {\includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{{image3}.pdf}};  & 
    \node (A4) {\includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{{image4}.pdf}}; \\
    \node (B1) {\includegraphics[trim=0.0cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\aelength]{{image5}.pdf}}; & 
    \node (B2) {\includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{{image6}.pdf}}; &
    \node (B3) {\includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{{image7}.pdf}}; &
    \node (B4) {\includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{{image8}.pdf}}; \\
    \node (C1) {\includegraphics[trim=0.0cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\aelength]{{image9}.pdf} }; & 
    \node (C2) {\includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{{image10}.pdf}}; &
    \node (C3) {\includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{{image11}.pdf}}; &
    \node (C4) {\includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{{image12}.pdf}}; \\
    \node (D1) {\includegraphics[trim=0.0cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\aelength]{{image13}.pdf}}; & 
    \node (D2) {\includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{{image14}.pdf}}; &
    \node (D3) {\includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{{image15}.pdf}}; &
    \node (D4) {\includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 0.0cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\aelength]{{image16}.pdf}}; \\
  };

  \node[fit=(A1) (A2) (A3) (A4)
            (B1) (B2) (B3) (B4)
            (C1) (C2) (C3) (C4)
            (D1) (D2) (D3) (D4),
            inner sep=0pt,
            ] (PIC) {};

  \draw[line width=1pt,arrows={-Stealth[length=4mm]}] ([xshift=-1em]PIC.north west) -- ([xshift=-1em]PIC.south west);
  \draw[line width=1pt,arrows={-Stealth[length=4mm]}] ([yshift=1em]PIC.north west) -- ([yshift=1em]PIC.north east);

  \node[anchor=south] (COL1/label) at ([yshift=1em]A1|-PIC.north) {Column Label  1};
  \node[anchor=south] (COL2/label) at ([yshift=1em]A2|-PIC.north) {Column Label  2};
  \node[anchor=south] (COL3/label) at ([yshift=1em]A3|-PIC.north) {Column Label  3};
  \node[anchor=south] (COL4/label) at ([yshift=1em]A4|-PIC.north) {Column Label  4};

  \node[anchor=center,rotate=90] (ROW1/label) at ([xshift=-1.5em]A1-|PIC.west) {ROW 1 label};
  \node[anchor=center,rotate=90] (ROW2/label) at ([xshift=-1.5em]B1-|PIC.west) {ROW 2 label};
  \node[anchor=center,rotate=90] (ROW3/label) at ([xshift=-1.5em]C1-|PIC.west) {ROW 3 label};
  \node[anchor=center,rotate=90] (ROW4/label) at ([xshift=-1.5em]D1-|PIC.west) {ROW 4 label};

  \node[blue,anchor=south,inner sep=0pt] at (C1.north) {Description of this pic below};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like it, but I will wait a few days before marking the solution. Using a table is smart, did not consider that.

Comment: Your first solution definitely is closest to what I am going to use. A final quibble - I find it quite difficult to align those row labels to the center of the row, vertically, without using `m` columns which mess up my figure scaling. Is that something easily achievable?

Comment: Marked your answer since it was closest to what I did (I put the right arrow in the tabular itself). Only aligning the vertical labels need some manual movement, but I guess if I want something simple that's the best I can do.

Comment: @kabanus I'm working on getting the centering...  Right now I almost have an answer but there's a bit of a fail I'm scratching my head about.

Comment: There's a saying, that goes something like *If the flames got the cedars, what will the moss do?* - nice to know this really is a bit difficult, I'm rooting for your success.

Comment: @kabanus A much more workable solution is now presented in part 1 of this answer.

Comment: Impressive - that final bit actually makes the solution even more complex than the TikZ one, so you were right about that.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses the picture environment.  It also packs the images into a minimal size using \vbox and \hbox with a `\space` between each row and column.

One annoying aspect of picture is that it uses its own units.  In this case I used `\unitlength=1pt` and used `\strip@pt` (renamed `\unit`) to convert lengths to picture units.

Rather than `\put` each label individually, it was easier to create a row of `\makebox`es.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[verbose,margin=0.1in]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{unit}{\let\unit=\strip@pt}%
  {\errmessage{\string\unit\space already exists.}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \sbox1{% row 1
            \includegraphics[trim=0.0cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\textwidth]{example-image}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\textwidth]{example-image}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\textwidth]{example-image}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\textwidth]{example-image}}%
        \sbox2{% row 2
            \includegraphics[trim=0.0cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\textwidth]{example-image}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\textwidth]{example-image}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\textwidth]{example-image}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\textwidth]{example-image}}%
        \sbox3{% row 3
            \includegraphics[trim=0.0cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\textwidth]{example-image}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\textwidth]{example-image}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\textwidth]{example-image}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\textwidth]{example-image}}%
        \sbox4{% row 4
            \includegraphics[trim=0.0cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.249\textwidth]{example-image}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\textwidth]{example-image}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\textwidth]{example-image}
            \includegraphics[trim=1.1cm 1.1cm 0 0,clip,width=0.230\textwidth]{example-image}}%
        \setbox0=\vbox{\settowidth{\lineskip}{\space}%
            \hbox{\usebox1}
            \hbox{\usebox2}
            \hbox{\usebox3}
            \hbox{\usebox4}}%
        \unitlength=1pt
        \centering
        \begin{picture}(\unit\dimexpr \wd0+14pt\relax,\unit\dimexpr \ht0+14pt\relax)(0,0)
          \put(14,0){\usebox0}
          \put(10,\unit\dimexpr\ht0+4pt\relax) {\vector(1,0){\unit\dimexpr\wd0+4pt\relax}}
          \put(14,\unit\dimexpr\ht0+8pt\relax) {\makebox[0.249\textwidth]{label1}
            \makebox[0.230\textwidth]{label2}
            \makebox[0.230\textwidth]{label3}
            \makebox[0.230\textwidth]{label4}}
          \put(10,\unit\dimexpr\ht0+4pt\relax){\vector(0,-1){\unit\dimexpr\ht0+4pt\relax}}
          \put(0,0){\rotatebox[origin=Bl]{90}{\makebox[\ht4]{label8}
            \makebox[\ht3]{label7}
            \makebox[\ht2]{label6}
            \makebox[\ht1]{label5}}}
        \end{picture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]