# Within a single paragraph, hang a wrapped line, but do not hang new lines

Tags: line-breaking, indentation

I'm writing a list, and would like the line hanging to work like this

[image: Want this line hanging]

I do not want to use separate paragraphs for each item in the list, and I do not want to use the list environments; I will be using the entire text of the list as an input argument to a new command that I hope will, in addition to placing the list where I want it, be able to make it hang properly--so the kind of list that I want would look something like this (I'm using the minipage environment here so that the lines will break just as in the image):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{units}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\nicefrac{1}{2} lb.\ (about 1\nicefrac{1}{2} cups) thinly sliced yellow onions\\
2 (about 1 cup) sliced green bell peppers\\
2 to 3 Tb olive oil, if necessary\\
2 cloves mashed garlic\\
Salt and pepper to taste
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

But, of course, that produces output that looks like this:

[image: Attempt with no hangs etc]

I understand that `\hangindent` will do the trick for paragraphs, but I do not want to use separate paragraphs for each item (and even if I did, `\hangindent` is local, so it'd have to go at the beginning of each item--also no good). When I try this anyway, hoping that it'll somehow know what I want (works surprisingly often with many other things LaTeX . . .), I get that this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{units}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\hangindent=1em
\nicefrac{1}{2} lb.\ (about 1\nicefrac{1}{2} cups) thinly sliced yellow onions\\
2 (about 1 cup) sliced green bell peppers\\
2 to 3 Tb olive oil, if necessary\\
2 cloves mashed garlic\\
Salt and pepper to taste
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image: Using hangindent to get something I don't want]

So no real surprise, but that means I'm officially out of ideas. Does someone know whether it's possible to, within a single paragraph, hang a wrapped line, but not hang new lines?

Comment: What you're describing looks like the way stanzas of poetry are set. Is there perhaps a verse environment that might work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the many answers I got here. The one I ended up using followed the suggestion of @LauraS to use the verse environment, which lent itself very well to what I was trying to do. I ended up using this file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{units}

\newcommand\step[2]{
                \centerline{\rule{0.45\linewidth}{0.1pt}}
                \vskip0.3em
                \begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
                \begin{verse}
                \hangindent=1em
                {\textbf{#1}}
                \end{verse}
                \end{minipage}
                \hskip1em
                \begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
                #2
                \end{minipage}
                }

\begin{document}

\step{\nicefrac{1}{2} lb.\ (about 1\nicefrac{1}{2} cups) thinly sliced yellow onions\\
2 (about 1 cup) sliced green bell peppers\\
2 to 3 Tb olive oil, if necessary\\
2 cloves mashed garlic\\
Salt and pepper to taste
}{
In the same skillet, cook the onions and peppers slowly in olive oil for about 10 minutes, or until tender but not browned. Stir in the garlic and season to taste. 
}

\end{document}
```

to produce this result:

[image: Just what I wanted!]

which is just what I had in mind: a command where I could enter a minimally-formatted list and have it not only placed where I wanted it, but also have the lines hang properly.

Thank you again to all!

Answer (score 6):

It makes no sense to me not to use paragraphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{units}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
\everypar{\setlength\hangindent{1em}}
\nicefrac{1}{2} lb.\ (about 1\nicefrac{1}{2} cups) thinly sliced yellow onions

2 (about 1 cup) sliced green bell peppers
2 to 3 Tb olive oil, if necessary

2 cloves mashed garlic

Salt and pepper to taste
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; this does work in the small example I gave, but as I'll eventually be using the entire text of the list as an input argument to a command, I don't want to break it up into paragraphs.

Answer (score 3):

Since using `\hangindent` is the obvious solution it is probably also the best one.  Nonetheless, if you want your text to *look* as though it is a single paragraph, you always have the option of messing with the syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 \newenvironment{hanginglines}[1][1em]
  {%
   \renewcommand\\{\par\hangindent#1}%
   \parindent0pt %
   \hangindent#1 %
  }
  {\par}

\begin{hanginglines}
 This is a very long line that I hope will wrap many times.  This is a very long line that I hope will wrap many times.
 \\
 This is a very long line that I hope will wrap many times.  This is a very long line that I hope will wrap many times.
 \\
 This is a very long line that I hope will wrap many times.  This is a very long line that I hope will wrap many times.
\end{hanginglines}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This could also have worked well for me. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

This is an addendum to Herbert's answer, which shows, how to re-use the text as an argument to a command, what @user16001 is looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{units}
\newenvironment{hangingpars}[1][1.2em]{%
  \parindent=0pt
  \everypar{\hangafter=1\hangindent=#1}}{\par}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\SavedStuff}{
\begin{hangingpars}[1em]
  \nicefrac{1}{2}\,lb.\ (about 1\nicefrac{1}{2} cups) thinly sliced yellow
  onions

  2 (about 1 cup) green bell peppers

  2 to 3 Tb olive oil, if necessary

  2 cloves mashed garlic

  Salt an pepper to taste
\end{hangingpars}
}

\SavedStuff\bigskip

\noindent\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
  \SavedStuff
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; indeed, something like this will work if I can't find a simpler solution, as I'd hoped to do.

Answer (score 0):

O offer this only as an alternative, and am quite aware that your original request was for an argument to a command. That said, and having wrestled with these issues for some time, and agreeing with you completely about minimizing markup -- I believe that the judicious use of environments ultimately simplifies and clarifies the process of dealing with recipes. Notice the absence of formatting in the ingredients (no `\\`), and the format of the method can be freely adjusted to suit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%% Thanks to egreg, a new lrbox that is *global*:
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43046/beamer-content-in-box-register-does-not-survive-endframe/43063#43063
%% Necessary because the minipage in 'ingreds' does not survive outside the environment.
\cslet{lrbox*}\lrbox
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname lrbox*\endcsname{\setbox}{\global\setbox}{}{}
\cslet{endlrbox*}\endlrbox

\newsavebox{\myingreds}
\newsavebox{\mymethod}

\newenvironment{ingreds}{%
    \begin{lrbox*}{\myingreds}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{4.5cm}% Change to suit
        \everypar{\hangindent1em}%
        \obeylines
}{%
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox*}%
}

\newenvironment{method}{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mymethod}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{6cm}% Change to suit
}{%
        \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}
    \usebox{\myingreds}\quad\usebox{\mymethod}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ingreds}
    \nicefrac{1}{2} lb.\ (about 1\nicefrac{1}{2} cups) thinly sliced yellow onion
     2 (about 1 cup) sliced green bell peppers
     2 to 3 Tb olive oil, if necessary
     2 cloves mashed garlic
     Salt and pepper to taste
\end{ingreds}
\begin{method}
 In the same skillet, cook the onions and peppers slowly in olive oil for about 10 minutes, or until tender but not browned. Stir in the garlic and season to taste.
\end{method}

\end{document}
```

[image: Recipe sample]