# hanging indent within indented texttt quote environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, indentation, typewriter

I'm working on a `memoir` class document which happens to use interparagraph spacing rather than indented first lines, yet I'm trying to create an environment that showcases sample text - I'm calling it `hangingsample` - where:

- the text is indented (like in a `quote` or `quotation` environment),
- the text is set in typewriter font (I use `\texttt` for this),
- the text is set `\raggedright`,
- each paragraph uses hanging indentation (like in APA referencing), and
- the interparagraph spacing is zero.

To illustrate:

[image: sample effect]

The only way I have managed to create this effect thus far is to do everything manually, combining the `figure`, `minipage`, and `hangparas` environment, the `\raggedright` command, and enveloping each separate paragraph in `\texttt{x}` and following up each paragraph with `\vspace{-\parskip}`:

```
Preceding text ...

\begin{figure}[h]
\hspace*{5mm}\begin{minipage}[h]{125mm}
\begin{hangparas}{5mm}{1}\RaggedRight
\texttt{Technic is ... LEGO.}\vspace{-\parskip}

\texttt{Technic sets are ... electric motors.}\vspace{-\parskip}

\texttt{The style of ... technic bricks.}\vspace{-\parskip}

\texttt{Lego Technic. ... wiki/Lego\_Technic}
\end{hangparas}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

Following text...
```

surely this cannot be the most economical way of doing it... I'm looking for a simple new (or renewed) environment that does all of these things.

So far, I have created the following environment:

```
\newenvironment{hangingsample}{%
\everypar{\hangafter=1 \setlength{\hangindent}{5mm}}\ttfamily\raggedright}
{\par%
}
```

Which achieves most points *except* the full indentation of the paragraphs.

Anyone any idea what I could do to solve this?

Most kind regards,

Cees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your own environment:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{ttquote}
 {\list{}{%
    \ttfamily\raggedright
    \setlength{\itemindent}{-1em}%
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\itemindent}%
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt plus 1pt}%
  }%
  \item[]}
 {\endlist}

\nonzeroparskip
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-3]

\begin{ttquote}
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]
\end{ttquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps. It's an adaptation of [Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61364/1952) to [Within a single paragraph, hang a wrapped line, but do not hang new lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61363/1952).
Being based in a `minipage`, this environment won't break between pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{ttpar}{%
\begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}
\everypar{\setlength\hangindent{1em}\ttfamily}
\BODY\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{ttpar}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]
\end{ttpar}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling @egreg's solution will work even better for me, but I will give both a try. Thanks!

Comment: @Krottsy No doubt! Any egreg's solution will work better than mine. He knows what he's doing. ;-)