# How to use an environment to load a vertical coffin that will be used outside the environment

Tags: environments, xparse, xcoffins

I would like to use an environment to fill a vertical coffin.  I find that I can fill the coffin this way, but that the poles get lost, in the sense the top pole (t) is treated as if it lies at the bottom of the coffin (the width also gets lost). I have to set the poles manually.

So, my question is whether there's a way to load the vertical coffin in an environment without losing the poles.  In the following MWE, my use of `\global` is a hack, and so maybe also the cause of the problem.

Notes: a) I need to use an environment for compatibility with other codes...I know that can get the final result directly without setting the coffin inside the environment and without losing the poles;  b) I have seen [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303585/119566) and its replies, but they don't quite address my question.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}    
\usepackage{xcoffins,lipsum,xparse}

\NewCoffin{\CoffinA}
\NewCoffin{\CoffinB}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\SetCoffinB{m}{%
    \SetVerticalCoffin{\CoffinB}{100mm}{#1}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{coffinB}{+b}{%
   \global\SetCoffinB{\noindent#1}%
}{}

\begin{document}

\SetVerticalCoffin{\CoffinA}{100mm}{%
    {\Large\bfseries\noindent A Big Heading}%
}

\begin{coffinB}
\lipsum[1]
\end{coffinB}

\SetHorizontalPole \CoffinB {t} {\TotalHeight} % <=== why should this be necessary?
\JoinCoffins\CoffinA[l,b]\CoffinB[l,t](0pt,0pt)

\TypesetCoffin\CoffinA

\end{document}
```

Without the `\SetHorizontalPole` command, I get this result, as if the top pole sits at the bottom of CoffinB:

[image]

With the `\SetHorizontalPole` for the top pole of CoffinB, I get this result, which is basically what I want:

[image]

Comment: `\global\SetCoffinB` is unlikely to do anything useful, you can not put `\global`  before arbitrary tex macros it will just apply arbitrarily to the first non expandable token in the expansion of `\SetCoffinB`

Comment: `\NewDocumentEnvironment{coffinB}{+b}{\gdef\tmp{\SetCoffinB{\noindent#1}}\aftergroup\tmp}{}` runs without error but I am not sure I understand the question well enough to know if that produces the desired effect.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Thanks, that code definitely fixes my problem. I would be great if you could unpack the ideas around `\gdef\tmp{...}\aftergroup\tmp` just a bit? What `\global` did for me originally was to get the coffin to exist outside the environment, and I gather that the expansion issue was responsible for the loss of poles?

Comment: if you put `\global` before a macro then you are lucky if anything useful happens, certainly it is by luck not design if it does anything before  `\SetCoffinB` if for example you try to make a global definition with `\global\newcommand\foo{..}` it just makes some internal temp assignment in the implementation of `\newcommand`  global, it doesn't affect the assignment to `\foo` at all.

Comment: Thanks, got it.  How does the `\gdef\tmp{...}\aftergroup\tmp` construction resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\global` can only be used before a tex primitive assignment. If you use it before a macro then it will perhaps make the first internal assignment in that macros expansion global, or it may do nothing or it may generate an error, depending on the internal implementation of the macro. Certainly for a coffin that requires several linked assignments for the box data itself and all the pole structures, a single `\global` can not possibly work.

If you use

```
 \NewDocumentEnvironment{coffinB}{+b}{%
   \gdef\tmp{\SetCoffinB{\noindent#1}}\aftergroup\tmp
}{}
```

then the body of the environment will be wrapped in the `\SetCoffinB` call but not executed, instead it is (globally) saved in a macro `\tmp` which is executed outside the group so essentially after the enviornment has finished.

Like any use of global variables this has some limitations, any nested use will break as the inner use would globally over-write `\tmp` messing up the outer one. The code could be made more robust to just smuggle the definition past one level of grouping without using a global assignment, but if nested use is not required, this is simpler.

Comment: Many thanks. Nested use is not required--although the smuggling operation does make me curious!